# External CSS file is not being loaded

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I added an external CSS to my theme. When I look at the  source code the external file is not being rendered.

In my html.tpl.php file I have:

```
<?php print $styles; ?>
```

In my template.php. file I have:

```
function fire_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  drupal_add_css('https://www.getmyfonts.com/assets/fonts/webfonts.css', array('type' => 'external'));

}

function fire_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  // Custom CSS for content types
     if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'fire') . '/assets/css/page-' . $vars['node']->type . '.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME));
  }

}
```

I have this in my .info

```
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style.css
stylesheets[all][] = 
sites/all/modules/datatables/dataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/rwd-table.min.css
stylesheets[print][] = assets/css/print.css
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?? Thank you